# How to access deleted term inside delete_product_cat action

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, actions

I want to run some code after a product category is deleted, in that function I want to access the name of the deleted category, and according to their docs I could do this:

```
add_action('delete_product_cat', 'sync_cat_delete', 10, 1);

function sync_cat_delete($term, $tt_id, $deleted_term, $object_ids){
    var_dump($deleted_term);
}
```

But when I do it, I get 500 internal server error

So what could be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: where exactly would this be displaying?

Comment: It would be displayed in the ajax response when a category is deleted, I placed var_dump there just for testing purposes, I could read the output with fiddler, an HTTP debugger.

Comment: I think your `add_action` call specifies only a single function parameter ( `1` ) but your function actually takes 4 parameters

Comment: @TomJNowell I figured that much, but according to the docs https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/delete_taxonomy/ there should be 4 parameters.

Comment: So you need to change the number of parameters to `4`, not `1` in your `add_action()`.

Comment: @AL-Kateb you have to specify how many parameters your function takes, afterall if an additional parameter is added it would break all existing uses of that action. That's why the parameter count field is there. See the `add_action` docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get 500 error, because you’ve added your filter incorrectly... It takes 4 params, but you register it as it was using only one.

```
add_action('delete_product_cat', 'sync_cat_delete', 10, 1); 
//  10 is priority, 1 is number of params to take

function sync_cat_delete($term, $tt_id, $deleted_term, $object_ids){
    var_dump($deleted_term);
}
```

So if you change that 1 to 4, it should be OK.

Comment: I just realized what this parameter does :facepalm: